# Latex - labeling tables while using foreach loop

Tags: loops, foreach, label, latex

I have a loop in latex, where I access 5 different tables to include in my document. The look has two elements - one variable indicating short name of the category (\n which can be A, O, I, R or H) and the variable that has the long name (\m, which can be "Apartment", "Office", etc).

This loop works as intended for caption and for input. But it does not work for "\label". In other words, the loop produces 5 tables, pulling the right files each time. It puts correct caption on these tables (Apartment, Office, etc), but \label does not get populated correctly. It produces only one label as "output_reg\n" instead of 5 labels as "output_reg_A", "output_reg_O", etc.
I would appreciate all the help I can get!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}


\foreach \n\m in {A/Apartments,O/Office,R/Retail,I/Industrial,H/Hotel}
{   \begin{table}
        \small
        \centering
        \caption{Regression results \n - \m } \label{output_reg_\n}
        \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
        a & a & \\
        a & a & 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table} 
        }

    content
    % I want to be able to reference the tables as  \ref{output_reg_A} and  \ref{output_reg_O and so on.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please don't just post code fragments, try to make a [mre] instead. Probably throwing a bunch of `\expandafter` might be worth a try, but without anything to test ...

Comment: Other then the missing closing `}` your minimal working example works fine. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sh3O5.png  Did you compile two times?

Comment: Can you show the .log file of your minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but better use `\caption{Regression results \n{} - \m }`. Otherwise the macro will shallow the space in front of the dash